# Intercept tap event in given condition

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I created a view with a UIPickerView which is showed when user push a button.

Now i need to make UIPickerView disappear when user tap anywhere on screen (obviously out of UiPickerView).

How can i intercept this tap only when UIPickerView is visible ? 
Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the `[ios iphone]` in the beginning of your question title. That's what tags are for. ;)

Comment: Thank you esqew. I change the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to attach a UIGestureRecognizer to the main view. As soon as someone taps the main view somewhere, you can get an event and remove your UIPickerView. Write something like this in you ViewController:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewWasTapped)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
```

In you viewWasTapped method you'll receive all Taps on the ViewControllers view.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's resolve only in part... i'm able to add a recognizer on a view. My problem is that i need to toggle the recognizer. If uipicker view is visible i add it .... when it's removed i remove recognizer too. 
I'd like to know if  this is a good method or not.

Comment: Do note that the recognizer needs to be placed on the _main_ view; that is, the view that encompasses your entire screen.